# Confusing Double Brace Initilizated Array

Tags: java, android

I am a bit confused with this hashmap that has an array list in it. I am looking to add each entry dynamically.

I have tried many times but I am unable to dynamically add an entry. Any suggestions?

```
   HashMap<String, List<Attraction>> ATTRACTIONS =
                new HashMap<String, List<Attraction>>() {{

                    put("Sydney", new ArrayList<Attraction>() {{
                        add(new Attraction(
                                "Sydney Opera House",
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae bibendum justo, vitae cursus velit. Suspendisse potenti.",
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae bibendum justo, vitae cursus velit. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse scelerisque risus justo, non tincidunt nibh blandit et. Vivamus elit lacus, luctus nec erat in, pharetra semper turpis. Quisque viverra nulla ligula, non pulvinar ante dictum sit amet. Vestibulum aliquet tortor mauris, vel suscipit nisl malesuada eget. Aliquam maximus dictum euismod. Maecenas leo quam, volutpat id diam eget, placerat fringilla ipsum. Nam pretium vehicula augue quis euismod.\n\nNam sed blandit magna. Vestibulum a fermentum arcu. Vestibulum et ligula at nisi luctus facilisis. Proin fermentum enim a nibh commodo finibus. Suspendisse justo elit, vulputate ut ipsum at, pellentesque auctor massa. Praesent vestibulum erat interdum imperdiet dapibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin varius orci vitae tempor vulputate.\n\nEtiam sed mollis orci. Integer et ex sed tortor scelerisque blandit semper id libero. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque tempor magna eget massa ultrices, et efficitur lectus finibus.",
                                Uri.parse("https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7fb5ybQhUbo/VGLWjIL4RmI/AAAAAAAAACM/2jLe_msj_tk/w600-no/IMG_0049.JPG"),
                                Uri.parse("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EFEw6s7mT6I/VGLkCH4Xt4I/AAAAAAAAADY/ZlznhaQvb8E/w600-no/DSC_2775.JPG"),
                                new LatLng(-33.858667, 151.214028),
                                "Sydney"
                        ));
                    }});

                }};
```

Comment: Then don't use the double brace initialization hack.

Comment: I tried using other methods but I am looking to somethin like this without the hack

Comment: Meaning I tried this

Comment: ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
        list.add(new Object()); 
        }

Comment: and plenty of other ways, but I simply do not understand how this is working so I can reconstruct it dynamically...correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using other methods but I am looking to somethin like this without the hack

Without double braces, you might write it something like

```
Map<String, List<Attraction>> ATTRACTIONS = new HashMap<>();
List<Attraction> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(new Attraction("Sydney Opera House",
    "Lorem ipsum ...",
    "Lorem ipsum ...",
    Uri.parse(
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7fb5ybQhUbo/VGLWjIL4RmI/AAAAAAAAACM/2jLe_msj_tk/w600-no/IMG_0049.JPG"),
    Uri.parse(
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EFEw6s7mT6I/VGLkCH4Xt4I/AAAAAAAAADY/ZlznhaQvb8E/w600-no/DSC_2775.JPG"),
    new LatLng(-33.858667, 151.214028), "Sydney"));
ATTRACTIONS.put("Sydney", al);
```

If you want to add another attraction for "Sydney", add it to `al`. If you want to add another city to your `ATTRACTIONS` make sure to create a `new List<Attraction>`.

Comment: I have tried something quite similar to this. I do not have a problem adding my own entries using a different method. It is just that I am looking to loop and add each entry. This is where I get lost. Loops seem to not apply when adding entries

Comment: @scooter The code calling `new Attraction` and `al.add` should be in the loop (to add `Attraction`s).

Comment: Seems like I was confused on what to put in the put parameter. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it will help if we explain what the "double brace hack" is actually doing.  Here's a simpler example:

```
Map<String, String> test =
            new HashMap<String, String>() 
{
    {
        put("key", "value");
        put("key2", "value2");
    }
};
```

Line 1 is the declaration.  Nothing interesting.

Line 2 is the start of an anonymous class declaration.  We are creating a subclass of `HashMap`.

Line 3 starts the anonymous class body.

Line 4 starts an instance initializer block

Line 5 & 6 statements in the initializer block

Line 7 end of initializer block

Line 8 end of anonymous class body.

The anonymous class works by chaining to the `HashMap` no-args constructor from the anon classes default constructor.  Then the initializer is executed, to call `put(...)` on `this`.  The end result is a pre-populated hashmap.

Then we delete a bunch of white space and we get:

```
HashMap<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
    put("key", "value");
    put("key2", "value2");
}};
```

For a list, you would use `add` rather than `put`.  However, there is another (IMO) simpler way to create a prepopulated list:

```
  List<String> test2 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Tree"});
```